# Existe la palabra "esquivador" en Español?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

Estaba buscando una palabra para traducir "dodger" del Inglés, que significa "persona que esquiva". Busqué en el sitio oficial de la RAE, pero aparentemente está suspendido por mejoras. En este otro sitio [Esquivador significado](https://www.nombra.me/significado-acentuacion-rimas/esquivador-ca.html) encontré que la palabra existe en Catalán, pero aparentemente (según ese sitio) sólo en Catalán. Como no sé que tan confiable es ese sitio mi pregunta es, existe la palabra "esquivador" en Español, aceptada por la RAE o en algún diccionario aunque sea?

Answer (score 3):

¿Qué te parece **evasor**?

Según el Diccionario Oxford, **[dodger](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dodger)** significa

> A person who engages in cunning tricks or dishonest practices to **evade**
> a debt or obligation.

Es decir, una persona que con triquiñuelas o prácticas deshonestas **evade** una deuda u obligación.

Según el DRAE (que está activo ahora):

> [evadir](https://dle.rae.es/evadir)
> 2. tr. Eludir con arte o astucia una dificultad prevista.

> [evasor](https://dle.rae.es/evasor)
>  1. adj. Que evade o se evade.

Es decir, **evasor** es aquel que elude (evade) con arte o astucia (cunning tricks) una dificultad prevista. Dado que la figura del **evasor de impuestos** es bastante común, podemos perfectamente entender esa dificultad como una deuda (debt).

Dependiendo del contexto concreto, creo que también podrías emplear **listillo**, **trápala** o **moroso**. O el verbo **escaquearse**, cuyo sustantivo sería "escaqueador", pero no parece muy correcto.

Creo que sería "escaqueador", no me viene ahora mismo una forma válida, puede que exista.

Por cierto, "esquivador" según Google se traduciría al castellano como ojeador. No parece corresponderse con "dodger".

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué te parece la palabra **perdidizo**?

**perdidizo, za.**
2. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que se escabulle.

Y se me ocurre que podrían encajar otras dos opciones:

- **elusivo**
- **evasivo**

Answer (score 0):

También existe *retrechero*:

> Que con artificios disimulados y mañosos trata de eludir la confesión de la verdad o el cumplimiento de lo debido.